# What is the Difference Between Maps and Dictionaries in terms of Worst Case Running Time?

Tags: java, data-structures, big-o

As the title says.

I have to list the worst case running times for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `SEARCH`
for maps and dictionaries, but aren't they both the same?

I.e for AVL tree implemented with MAP or Dictionary, shouldn't
all 3 operations take O(logn)?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own tests?

Comment: Note that [`Dictionary` is obsolete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) "This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class."

Comment: @sherb Determining time complexity by writing tests is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A map or a dicitionary is an abstract notion for a data structure which supports several operations(insert etc.). It does not have any specific time/space complexity. Time complexity actually depends on a concrete data structure(such as a hash table or a binary search tree) which is used to implement it. So you question about time complexity of operations on an abstract map or dictionary does not make much sense.